# Bootstrap form pattern mandatory validation

Tags: forms, validation, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap I would to create a form with a **pattern mandatory validation** for the addresses, where the value must be:
"Free input text" + "5 numeric characters" *(mandatory)*

Example:
**Rome - 65498**

How to do that?

Comment: Would you be able to ask the user for a 3 letter country code instead? If so, I have a solution that in one input allows only 3 letters, a dash, and then 5 numbers (ex: usa - 12345).

Comment: The user must insert first a text (free input), then at the end after the symbol "-", he must insert 5 numbers mandatory.

Comment: Okay, and do you have a minimum and maximum length for that free input text? Generally you would want to limit the user to some length range.

Comment: For the free input text, minimum could be 4 characters and maximum 60 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:
   https://jsfiddle.net/Lxv4f7qe/2/

Code:

```
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Title</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>

        <form class="p-5" action="POST">
            <label for="zip_code">Optional Spaces:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" pattern="([A-Za-z]{4,60} ?- ?\d{5})?" title="Zip code"><br><br>
            <label for="zip_code">Required Spaces:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" pattern="([A-Za-z]{4,60} - \d{5})?" title="Zip code"><br><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a helpful link on the **pattern** matching html input attribute: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145

Comment: It works! Can you provide the spaces mandatory before and after the dash? And so, for example: Rome - 43523

Comment: Here you go: <input type="tel" id="zip_code" name="zip_code"
        pattern="([A-Za-z]{4,60} - \d{5})?" title="Zip code"> 

Let me know if you want me to edit the demo or the pasted code above.

Comment: edited the demo and the code for you, glad i could help :)